# Cookie free Domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

My project is a cakephp Project. All static content are in webroot. Is there anyway to specify via apache configs, htacess or something else to not to send cookies. I mean is there anyway to specify that contents of this folder with sub-folders should be cookie free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the cookies are tied to the domain. The browser *will* send all cookies set on *.yourdomain.com. Your best bet is to create a "static.yourdomain.com" virtualhost, and ensure that your application does not set cookies for this domain. This way you can keep your existing folder structure.

Of course, it's far better to host on a cookie-free CDN like Amazon Cloudfront but that might be much more effort.

Comment: But since you can't use a wildcard you'd also need a different subdomain for your regular content like www.yourdomain.com. Then you set PHP cookie parameters to only set a cookie for that exact domain name. Effectively keeping your static.yourdomain.com domain cookie-free.